# Webpack React - component issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, single-spa

I already install the 'yarn add cdbreact' and 'yarn add react-router-dom' but why I am having this error?

This is my code in `Sidebar.js`

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100vh', overflow: 'scroll initial' }}
    >
      <CDBSidebar textColor="#fff" backgroundColor="#333">
        <CDBSidebarHeader prefix={<i className="fa fa-bars fa-large"></i>}>
          <a
            href="/"
            className="text-decoration-none"
            style={{ color: 'inherit' }}
          >
            Sidebar
          </a>
        </CDBSidebarHeader>
 
        <CDBSidebarContent className="sidebar-content">
          <CDBSidebarMenu>
            <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="activeClicked">
              <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="columns">Dashboard</CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to="/tables" activeClassName="activeClicked">
              <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="table">Tables</CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to="/profile" activeClassName="activeClicked">
              <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="user">Profile page</CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to="/analytics" activeClassName="activeClicked">
              <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="chart-line">
                Analytics
              </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            </NavLink>
 
            <NavLink
              exact
              to="/hero404"
              target="_blank"
              activeClassName="activeClicked"
            >
              <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="exclamation-circle">
                404 page
              </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
            </NavLink>
          </CDBSidebarMenu>
        </CDBSidebarContent>
 
        <CDBSidebarFooter style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <div
            style={{
              padding: '20px 5px',
            }}
          >
            Sidebar Footer
          </div>
        </CDBSidebarFooter>
      </CDBSidebar>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default Sidebar;
```

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot
> 1:0
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
> binary file)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to add the webpack loader for the fonts. Try to add this section:

```
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

Something like this:

```
 module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
     filename: 'bundle.js',
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.css$/i,
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
       },
       {
         test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
         type: 'asset/resource',
       },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
     ],
   },
 };
```